# Degree of universal cover of simple Lie group

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, covering-spaces, fundamental-groups

I have seen a statement that if $\mathfrak{g}$ is a simple Lie algebra, then there are only finitely many Lie groups with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. Equivalently, the simply connected group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ has finite center. Equivalently, the fundamental group of a Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ is finite.

Can anyone provide a proof or reference for any of these equivalent statements?

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86677/the-fundamental-group-of-lie-group) and the linked questions and references, which together give the result.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me there! But the first answer is only for compact Lie groups, and I certainly hope I don’t need to use Ricci curvature like in the second answer. (And the links in the comments are broken.)